# AJAX jQuery Freezing IE/Safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, internet-explorer, safari

At my wits end here.

Im running this script

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery(window).ready(function(){
        //alert('running');
        var sold = false;

        var leads = [            
            ["one", 120],

            ["two", 0]
        ];

            jQuery.each(leads, function(index, value) {
                var _data = "";
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/wp-content/plugins/cUrl/submit_lead.php?lead=" + value[0],
                    dataType: "json",
                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    timeout: value[1] * 1000, //Yes i need to wait 120 seconds for "one"
                    async: false,
                    cache: false
                }).success(function(data) {
                    _data = data;
                    console.log(data.status + " Lead: "+ value[0]);
                    if (data.status == "sold") {
                        sold = true;
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "/wp-content/plugins/cUrl/submit_lead.php?resetSession",
                            dataType: "json",
                            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            async: false,
                            cache: false
                        }).success(function() {
                            //Silence is golden.
                        });
                        window.location.href = data.link;
                    }
                }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                    console.log("ERROR: " + textStatus + " Lead: " + value[0]);
                });

                if (_data.status == "sold") {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            if (!sold) {
                //If we get here, None of the leads were sold.
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/wp-content/plugins/cUrl/submit_lead.php?resetSession",
                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    cache: false
                }).success(function(data) {
                  //Silence is golden.
                });
                window.location.href = '/thank-you.php';
            }        

    });
</script>
```

The script takes some info submits it to submit_lead.php which will return a json response with a status, a message and a link. Once it has this link it needs to call the same script with ?resetSession and the redirect the user to the link received.

I have a sync turned off because I need to wait until I get a response from "one" before trying "two", because if I receive a link there's no point trying the next one.

When the script runs on FF or Chrome, it runs fine. There is a little animation that plays while the requests are going through and once a link is returned it redirects accordingly.

When the script runs in <= IE8 or Safari, the page sorta loads half then waits (The animation loads but does not animate.). Once the ajax response has returned the page suddenly springs to life and then you get redirected.

I have tried window ready and document ready and nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: use a callback and turn async on

Answer (score 0):

Like i said in the comments, turn async back on.

Add your redirect or whatever operations you want to perform in the callback from the ajax function. Thats most likely the reason you are getting locking.